# Why is my React function not waiting for the SweetAlert confirmation?

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert

I am trying to get the swalDelete function to wait for a response from SweetAlert, but I am getting the 'doDelete' log right after clicking the 'Delete' button. How do I get the log to wait for a response? What am I doing wrong?

Locations.js

```
async function swalDelete(value, canDelete){
    let doDelete = await Delete(locationInUseFxn(), canDelete, value);
    // doDelete gets logged right after clicking the delete button.
    console.log('doDelete', doDelete); 
};

<Button
    onClick={() => swalDelete(rowData, canDelete)}>Delete</Button>
```

Delete.js

```
export const Delete = (inUse, canDelete, value) => {
...
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Delete record?',
        text: 'This action cannot be undone.',
        icon: 'question',
        confirmButtonText: 'Delete',
        confirmButtonColor: '#DC004E',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        reverseButtons: true,
        focusConfirm: false,
        focusCancel: false,
        scrollbarPadding: false
    }).then((result) => {
        return result.isConfirmed;
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the Promise from `Delete` so it can be awaited. Without this your code is simply awaiting the void return of the non-asynchronous `Delete` function (i.e. `Delete` isn't declared `async` so it doesn't implicitly return a Promise).

```
export const Delete = (inUse, canDelete, value) => {
  ...
  return Swal.fire({ // <-- return Promise
    title: 'Delete record?',
    text: 'This action cannot be undone.',
    icon: 'question',
    confirmButtonText: 'Delete',
    confirmButtonColor: '#DC004E',
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    reverseButtons: true,
    focusConfirm: false,
    focusCancel: false,
    scrollbarPadding: false
  }).then((result) => {
    return result.isConfirmed;
  });
};
```

Comment: That was too easy. Thank you. I will mark it as the answer as soon as SO allows me to do so.